# How to remove the reflection in Docky?

Tags: customization, docky

I don't like the reflections on the dock when in 3D mode. If find it hard to see the indicators of what's running. Could someone give me steps on how to do it and how to undo it (just incase I don't like it). Thanks

[image: The docky with the reflection]

Comment: you can change the theme or do a vertical offset

Comment: I like the themes I have and I'd rather keep the dock on the bottom. I'm wondering if there's some kind of script I could run like I did to remove the docky icon that would remove the reflection

Comment: you dont need a script to remove docky icon , you can do it from dconf tools i guess... by of setting i mean moving the dock down a few pixel so that the reflection/shadows vanish all together!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. If you solved it, please post an answer explaining how it was solved (answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but [encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). If the question no longer applies you may voluntarily delete/close it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to disable the reflection in Docky. However, Docky has been (for all intents and purposes) replaced by Plank, which is created by the original developer of the Docky Dock.

Here's how to install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/docky
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install plank
```

Source: [here](http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Plank%3aInstalling).